# HTML Scraper Script w/ Pagination

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I'm trying to pull in lists like https://letterboxd.com/prof_ratigan/list/top-1000-films-of-all-time-calculated/detail/page/1/ -- but all 1000 entries / 10 pages of 100 items. e.g. `LBLIST(A1)` would bring across the movie title and year. The full URL for the list would be in A1.

I figure the pagination would be an array that pulls the max from `//div[@class='paginate-pages']/ul/li` and creates `{1,10}`

Titles are `//h2/a` and dates are `//h2/small/a` -- returning this

| Title | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Casablanca | 1942 |
| Citizen Kane | 1941 |
| The Godfather | 1972 |
| City Lights | 1931 |
| 12 Angry Men | 1957 |
| Metropolis | 1927 |
| Rear Window | 1954 |

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve all values of "Title" and "Year" from "https://letterboxd.com/prof_ratigan/list/top-1000-films-of-all-time-calculated/detail/page/#/".
- In your situation, there are 10 pages and 1000 items in the site.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, in order to parse the HTML, [cheerio for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs) is used. So, please install the Google Apps Script library as follows.

In the current stage, it seems that the library project key is `1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0`. Please install this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#add_a_library_to_your_script_project)

When this library is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const maxPage = 10; // From your question, the max page number is 10.
  const reqs = [...Array(maxPage)].map((_, i) => ({ url: `https://letterboxd.com/prof_ratigan/list/top-1000-films-of-all-time-calculated/detail/page/${i + 1}/`, muteHttpExceptions: true }));
  const values = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs).flatMap((r, i) => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
      return [["Values couldn't be retrieved.", reqs[i].url]];
    }
    const $ = Cheerio.load(r.getContentText());
    const ar = $('li > div.film-detail-content > h2 > a , small > a').toArray();
    return [...Array(Math.ceil(ar.length / 2))].map((_) => {
      const temp = ar.splice(0, 2);
      return [$(temp[0]).text().trim(), Number($(temp[1]).text().trim())];
    });
  });

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In this case, 1000 items are retrieved.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to use this script as a custom function, how about the following script? In this case, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE()` to a cell.

  ```
    function SAMPLE() {
      const maxPage = 10; // From your question, the max page number is 10.
      const reqs = [...Array(maxPage)].map((_, i) => ({ url: `https://letterboxd.com/prof_ratigan/list/top-1000-films-of-all-time-calculated/detail/page/${i + 1}/`, muteHttpExceptions: true }));
      return UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs).flatMap((r, i) => {
        if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
          return [["Values couldn't be retrieved.", reqs[i].url]];
        }
        const $ = Cheerio.load(r.getContentText());
        const ar = $('li > div.film-detail-content > h2 > a , small > a').toArray();
        return [...Array(Math.ceil(ar.length / 2))].map((_) => {
          const temp = ar.splice(0, 2);
          return [$(temp[0]).text().trim(), Number($(temp[1]).text().trim())];
        });
      });
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the current HTMl in the URL. If the specification of the site is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [cheerio for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs)

Comment: yes!! Thank you so much. I modified the SAMPLE function to take a URL in the function itself. Thanks so much for this. Its perfect.

Comment: @tomf Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I'm building a large static movie watchlist and this is one of a few tools with it. Thanks again! Its perfect.

Comment: how could I also fetch attribute tags? e.g. if there were `<meta content="8 Million Ways to Die (1986)" itemprop="name">`, how could I retrieve '8 Million Ways to Die (1986)'?

Comment: @tomf I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?