# Scraping <meta> content with Cheerio

Tags: google-apps-script

[Tanaike helped me with this amazing script using Cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694363/html-scraper-script-w-pagination/72694796). The original was for Letterboxd, but this one is to pull in a watchlist from Trakt.tv ([sample watchlist](https://trakt.tv/users/jerrylaslow/history)).

As it is right now it pulls in the watched date and the title, but I'd also like to pull in the content from the meta tag for each item.

```
<meta content="8 Million Ways to Die (1986)" itemprop="name">
```

I tried using `$('[itemprop="name"]').attr('content');` but it doesn't accept the .attr piece.

Here is the full script as it is now, returning the watched date in the Col1 and the title in Col2.

```
/**
* Returns Trakt watchlist by username
* @param pages enter the number of pages in the list. Default is 10
* @customfunction
*/
function TRAKT(pages=10) {
    const username = `jerrylaslow`
    const maxPage = pages; 
    const reqs = [...Array(maxPage)].map((_, i) => ({ url: `https://trakt.tv/users/`+ username +`/history/all/added?page=${i + 1}`, muteHttpExceptions: true }));
    return UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs).flatMap((r, i) => {
      if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        return [["Values couldn't be retrieved.", reqs[i].url]];
      }
      const $ = Cheerio.load(r.getContentText());
      const ar = $(`a.titles-link > h3.ellipsify, h4 > span.format-date`).toArray();
      return [...Array(Math.ceil(ar.length / 2))].map((_) => {
        const temp = ar.splice(0, 2);
        const watchDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date($(temp[1]).text().trim().replace(/T|Z/g, " ")),"GMT","yyyy-MM-dd");
        const title = $(temp[0]).text().trim();
        return [watchDate,title];
      });
    });
  }
```

The values can be pulled with this, so I know there isn't any sort of blocking in play.

```
=IMPORTXML(
  "https://trakt.tv/users/jerrylaslow/history",
  "//meta[@itemprop='name']/@content")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function TRAKT(pages = 10) {
  const username = `jerrylaslow`
  const maxPage = pages;
  const reqs = [...Array(maxPage)].map((_, i) => ({ url: `https://trakt.tv/users/` + username + `/history/all/added?page=${i + 1}`, muteHttpExceptions: true }));
  return UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs).flatMap((r, i) => {
    if (r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
      return [["Values couldn't be retrieved.", reqs[i].url]];
    }
    const $ = Cheerio.load(r.getContentText());
    const ar = $(`a.titles-link > h3.ellipsify, h4 > span.format-date`).toArray();
    return [...Array(Math.ceil(ar.length / 2))].map((_) => {
      const temp = ar.splice(0, 2);
      const c = $(temp[0]).parent('a').parent('div').parent('div').find('meta').toArray().find(ff => $(ff).attr("itemprop") == "name"); // Added
      const watchDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date($(temp[1]).text().trim().replace(/T|Z/g, " ")), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      const title = $(temp[0]).text().trim();
      return [watchDate, title, c ? $(c).attr("content") : ""]; // Modified
    });
  });
}
```

- When this modified script is run, the value of `content` is put to 3rd column. If you want to put it to other column, please modify `return [watchDate, title, c ? $(c).attr("content") : ""];`.

Comment: amazing! My own efforts weren't even close, it seems. Thank you so much for this! You're a life saver.

Comment: @tomf Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.